# NULL value not getting inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table with few NULL columns.. and I have created a stored procedure.

When I enter values in the controls in the web form, I need to type in values in all the fields
or else, I get an error saying:

> *System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.*

on the line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mob2", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text)));
```

I tried even doing

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mob2", int.parse(TextBox5.Text)));
```

But I'm unable to leave it as NULL in the TextBox control..

In the table, the datatype is `numeric(10,0)`.. in the stored procedure I have mentioned as `nvarchar(10)` and while inserting I have converted like this,

```
Convert(numeric(10,0),@Mob2)
```

But it seems to not getting converted..

Comment: I think you need to add more of what you want here, the reason for crashing is that the convert method wants an actual integer to convert and an empty string isn't a valid integer. What do you actually want to happen if the field is empty? Pass in NULL? What do you want to happen if the field is "hello" (ie an invalid integer)?

Comment: Do you want to make the TextBox hold a null value? I think it can only be string.Empty. Use TryParse..

Comment: Exactly.. If the field is let empty I need the value to go in as NULL..

Comment: Make sure you understand there is a difference between the C# `null` and the  .NET `DBNull.Value`

Comment: **WHY** do you make the stored proc parameter `nvarchar(10)` when your datatype in the table is `numeric(10,0)` ?? Make those types **the same** - then you can save yourself another conversion!

Comment: @marc_s I've changed the datatype in SP as numeric(10,0).. Now how do I let user to let the Textbox field empty? Its still giving error: `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric`

Answer (score 3):

`Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text)` will always fail for empty strings. So check that:

```
object val = string.IsNullOrEmpty(theString) ? (object)DBNull.Value
                                             : int.Parse(theString);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm unable to understand.. I've changed the datatype in SP as numeric(10,0).. Now how do I let user to let the Textbox field empty?

Answer (score 1):

Check value of TextBox5.Text, problem related with textbox value

Comment: I am leaving it empty. When I type some value there, it gets inserted with no error. When I leave it NULL, it doesn't get inserted with error as mentioned

Answer (score 1):

make sure mobile number is required field

If not than make sure in your database table `mobile number` field is unchecked for `NULL` in your database table. That's way you get this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse a null string to an integer which you can't to you should use either [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.80%29) or if you a null value inserted into the database field something along the lines of:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mob2", 
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox5.Text.Trim()) ?int.parse(TextBox5.Text) 
: SqlInt32.Null));
```

which inserts the Sql Int32 null value into the database if TextBox5.Text == null or empty

**UPDATE TO ADDRESS USER COMMENTS**
If you're using numeric(10,0), convert the TextBox5 value to decimal and change your stored procedure from varchar(10) to numeric(10,0) to match the table column data type, then you can use code similar to:

```
SqlParameter numericParameter = new SqlParameter("NumericValue",SqlDbType.Decimal);
numericParameter.Precision = 10;
numericParameter.Scale = 0;
numericParameter.Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox5.Text.Trim()) ?decimal.parse(TextBox5.Text) 
: SqlInt32.Null);
```

Comment: Now it says- `Error converting data type nvarchar to int.`

Comment: @Girish how is `@Mob2` defined? 'cos nothing in this answer is nvarchar...If the Parma is nvarchar, why are you using Convert.ToInt32 in the question?

Comment: I've changed the datatype in SP as numeric(10,0).. Now how do I let user to let the Textbox field empty? Its still giving error: `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.`